# How do I get a pythonic list of all the pytest tests in a folder?

Tags: pytest

Something like --collect, only from python and not cmd, that returns a list of paths. I tried to see how pytest does it and I can't seem ro find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All collected tests would be stored as attribute `items` of `session`.
You can access `session` object by

1. session level `fixture`
2. pytest plugins, for example: `pytest_runtestloop` or `pytest_sessionstart`

Example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def get_all_tests(request):
    items = request.session.items
    all_tests_names = [item.name for item in items]
    all_tests_locations = [item.location for item in items]
    # location is a tuple of (file_path, linenumber, Classname.methodname)
```

If you want more info about object `session` or `item`, of cause you can read the docs or source code, but I prefer to use `pdb.set_trace` to dig into the object.